# $scope.data undefined in controller

Tags: angularjs

I can't use $scope.data in my controller, it's undefined, can you help please ?

Thanks

contact.html

```
<textarea cols="40" rows="6" name="message" id="message" class="panelInputs" placeholder="Message" ng-model="data.message" ng-change="displayscope()"></textarea>
```

controllers.js

```
angular.module('BoardLine.controllers', ['BoardLine.services'])
.controller('ContactCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, sessionService, isPhoneGap, isIOS) {
  console.log($scope.data);
  $scope.displayscope = function() {
    console.log("displayscope : ");
    console.log($scope.data);
  }
})
```

app.js

```
angular.module('BoardLine', ['ionic', 'ngCookies', 'ui.unique', 'BoardLine.controllers', 'BoardLine.services', 'BoardLine.filters'])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define the property `data` like `$scope.data = {}` in your controller first. Because your `ng-model` binds to `data.message`, while `data` is `undefined`. So the `message` cannot be assigned.

Answer (score 2):

In your controller you should declare $scope.date object

```
    angular.module('BoardLine.controllers', ['BoardLine.services'])
.controller('ContactCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, sessionService, isPhoneGap, isIOS) {
//add this
$scope.data = {};

  console.log($scope.data);
  $scope.displayscope = function() {
    console.log("displayscope : ");
    console.log($scope.data);
  }
})
```